# Status bar turns white when using custom Toolbar

Tags: java, android, toolbar, statusbar, navigationview

I'm using NavigationView with a Toolbar. Status bar's background is white. If you have any questions just comment it before downvoting I'll look at them asap.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Try something like: `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`

Comment: How did you defined @color/colorPrimaryDark (in colors.xml)?

Comment: Upload your color.xml file

Comment: @GuilhermeP please check out my latest edit on post

Comment: @ArbenMaloku I tried that, result doesn't changes

Comment: btw If I use CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout together on toolbar status bar is normal but in this case FrameLayout overlaps toolbar

Comment: When you get status bar color is white?Share the screenshot if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add this attribute **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"** in parent (DrawerLayout). To fix the white status bar while using it.

To know more about it refer this link [Why would I want to fitsSystemWindows?](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.lh20tfjy3)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_dark"
    app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

Comment: Wow, is it that simple? Thank you very much.